# AngularJS Postponing Page Display Until $timeouts have passed

Tags: angularjs

I have a bunch of directives that use $timeouts to apply styles. This causes a few milliseconds where there is some content that is not properly displayed. Is there a way of postponing AngularJS from displaying the next template until all the $timeout styles have been applied?

Comment: Please show some code, so we can suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1):

ng-cloak is meant for cloaking elements until they are ready for rendering but I haven't had much joy with it.

I tend to use a variable in the controller:

```
$scope.loading = false
$timeout(function() {
  // do stuff
  $scope.loading = true
}, 2000);
```

Then in the view:

```
<div ng-if="loading===true">
  <!-- your page -->
</div>
```

Also I've found that you should put your Angular `<script>` in HTML head.

If you put it in footer, like most people suggest, then the page has no idea what ng-if means when it encounters it. This causes the element to flash up on the screen. Then when Angular loads it, it hides it. This results in a flashing effect on page load.

Comment: This was also my suggestion, but I'd name the variable `loaded` (or some other past-tense term), which is more semantically correct.